# Get ID of Clicked list item returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list

```
<ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#" id="profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="change_password">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="payment_settings">Payment Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

And would like to get the id of the list item once clicked, how would i do this?

I have tried the below and get undefined?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {

    console.log(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` event should be bound to certain element(s), which could be selected using particular selector:

```
$('.submenu > li > a').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("a").click(function () {

    console.log(this.id);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submenu li a").click(function () {

    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZYSv/)